# I'm having problems with validating a page

Tags: html, validation

I'm having problems validating my page to strict 1. Can anyone help me? It keeps on showing:

> - Line 48, Column 4: document type does not allow element "`h2`" here; assuming missing "`li`" start-tag
>
>   ```
>   <h2>Current job vacancies</h2>
>   ```
> - Line 60, Column 6: end tag for "`li`" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
>
>   ```
>   </div>
>   ```
>
>   You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "`/>`" instead of "`>`".
> - Line 48, Column 1: start tag was here
>
>   ```
>   <h2>Current job vacancies</h2>
>   ```
> - Line 60, Column 6: end tag for "`ul`" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
>
>   ```
>   </div>
>   ```
>
>   You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "`/>`" instead of "`>`".
> - Line 45, Column 37: start tag was here
>
>   ```
>   <a href="#">Job Vacancies</a> <ul id="jobvacancies">
>   ```

Here is my page:

```
1.<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
2.<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
3.<head>
4.<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
5.<title>Royal Aura club and Restaurant</title>
6.<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="restyle.css" />
7.</head>
8.
9.<body>
10.
11.
12.<div id="main">
13.
14.
15.<div id="commonlinksbar">
16.|<a class="linker "href="#">about us</a>|
17.<a class="linker "href="#">contact us</a>| 
18.<a class="linker "href="sitemap.html">site map</a>|
19.<a class="linker "href="#">copyright</a>|
20.
21.</div>
22.
23.
24.
25.
26.
27.<div id="header"> 
28.<img class="logo" src="relogo.jpg"alt="auramayfair logo" width="87" height="98" />
29.<h1> Royal Aura club and Restaurant</h1>
30.
31.<div id="nav">
32.<p><a href="index.html">HOME</a><a href="restaurant.html">RESTAURANT</a> <a href="#">GALLERY</a><a href="#">GUEST LIST</a><a href="jobvacancies.html">JOB VACANCIES</a></p>
33.</div> 
34.
35.
36.
37.
38.
39.
40.<div id="content">
41.
42.<div id="breadcrumbs">
43.<a href="index.html">Home</a> >
44.
45.<a href="#">Job Vacancies</a> <ul id="jobvacancies">
46.
47.
48.<h2>Current job vacancies</h2>
49.<p>Royal aura club and restaurant are currently recruiting people to join our friendly atmosphere.</p> 
50.
51.<p>Chef - Skilled Cook with experience in traditional Pan Asian cooking required. The successful candidate will be responsible for all domestic cooking; preparing and producing a range of appetizing meals. The successful candidate will have previous experience within a similar role and will possess natural enthusiasm and a strong passion for food.</p>
52.
53.<hr />
54.
55.<p>Bar staff- Experienced Bar Staff are needed for regular 5-8 hour shifts Fridays and Saturdays. We are looking for someone with previous bar experience, cash handling experience and excellent customer services skills are essential, as is a well-presented appearance and polite manner.</p>
56.
57.
58.<p>Applicants should send their CV with a covering letter to:<a href="mailto:royalaura@hotmail.com">jobs@royalaura.com</a></p>
59.
60.</div>
61.</div>
62.<div id="footer">
63.<p> Copy Right Royal Aura Club 2006</p>
64.</div> 
65.
66.</div>
67.</div>
68.</body>
69.</html>
```

---

Here is the new code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Royal Aura club and Restaurant</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="restyle.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">


        <div id="commonlinksbar">
    |<a class="linker "href="#">about us</a>|
     <a class="linker "href="#">contact us</a>|                                                         
     <a class="linker "href="sitemap.html">site map</a>|
     <a class="linker "href="#">copyright</a>|


    </div>




<div id="header">   
<img class="logo" src="relogo.jpg"alt="auramayfair logo" width="87" height="98" />
<h1> Royal Aura club and Restaurant</h1>

<div id="nav">
     <p><a href="index.html">HOME</a><a href="restaurant.html">RESTAURANT</a> <a href="#">GALLERY</a><a href="#">GUEST LIST</a><a href="jobvacancies.html">JOB VACANCIES</a></p>
   </div>       






        <div id="content">

                    <div id="breadcrumbs">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a> >

                    <a href="#">Job Vacancies</a> <div id="jobvacancies">




<div id="jobs">
<h2>Current job vacancies</h2>
<p>Royal aura club and restaurant are currently recruiting people to join our friendly atmosphere.</p>  
<p>Chef - Skilled Cook with experience in traditional Pan Asian cooking required. The successful candidate will be responsible for all domestic cooking; preparing and producing a range of appetizing meals. The successful candidate will have previous experience within a similar role and will possess natural enthusiasm and a strong passion for food.</p>

<hr />

<p>Bar staff- Experienced Bar Staff are needed for regular 5-8 hour shifts Fridays and Saturdays. We are looking for someone with  previous bar experience, cash handling experience and excellent customer services skills are essential, as is a well-presented appearance and polite manner.</p>

<p>Applicants should send their CV with a covering letter to:<a href="mailto:royalaura@hotmail.com">jobs@royalaura.com</a></p>



</div>
    <div id="footer">
    <p> Copy Right Royal Aura Club 2006</p>
    </div> 

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have an unordered list opening tag:

```
<ul id="jobvacancies">
```

And you have an `<h2>` right after:

```
<h2>Current job vacancies</h2>
```

But a `<li>` is missing. All elements inside an `<ul>` must be inside a `<li>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

you open an unordered list `<ul>` but never put list items `<li>` into it. also, you never close the `<ul>` element.

maybe you meant to create another div?

Comment: How can i resolve this problem? If i remove <ul id="jobvacancies"> the page stretchs. I rather not put li from h2 on wards. Any ideas what i can do? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want the page to stretch then I suggest change the height and width properties of the

```
 <div id="content">
```

and remove the

```
<ul>
```

completely.  BTW which way does you page stretch?

Comment: Hi i have sorted out the ul problem - now its saying </body>✉ 
You may have neglected to close an element, or perhaps you meant to "self-close" an element, that is, ending it with "/>" instead of ">". The body is closed. I don't understand what its saying

Comment: Please post the latest bit of code.. preferably without the line numbers on the left.